# Having trouble understanding float issue in a simple UI layout

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a css layout using float left and float right property.
The following is the correct layout
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

    </head>
    <body>
        <header> header</header>
        <div class="clearfix wrapper">

            <div class="left">
                Left content
            </div>

            <div class="right">
                right content
            </div>
              <div class="center">
                responsive width Main content
            </div>
        </div>
        <footer> footer</footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is corresponding css:

```
:root {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
::before,
::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.center{
  background:lightblue;
}

.left{
  background:gold;
}
.right{
  background:yellow;
}
footer , header{
  background:CornflowerBlue;
}
.wrapper{
  overflow:hidden;
}
.center,.left,.right{
  text-align:center;
  
}
.left,.right{
  width:100px;
}


.left{
  float:left;
}
.right{
  float:right;
}
```

After I changed my HTML structure by moving div with center class name between div:left and div: right.

```
        <div class="clearfix wrapper">

            <div class="left">
                Left content
            </div>
              <div class="center">
                responsive width Main content
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                right content
            </div>

        </div>
```

I got following  incorrect layout:
[image]

Could anyone explain to me why I got the above issue? I am more interested in understanding the reason cause such an issue. Thanks!

https://jsfiddle.net/Boyanliuu/hf2temwd/13/

Comment: .center { width: calc(100% - 200px); float: left; }

Comment: please edit your question and put both layouts together, it will let us easily see what the issue is.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I just updated js fiddle which include both layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tried to understand how `float` works for the first time I had to inspect the elements in Google Chrome to finally get into my head that **`float` removes the element from the normal flow of the page**.

To demonstrate here is a *scenario 1* where u have `.left`, `.center`, `.rigth` - all of them have `float: none;` i.e. these elements don't have `float`. What you see is the *NORMAL FLOW*.

```
<div class="left" style="float: none;">Left</div>
<div class="center">responsive width Main content</div>
<div class="right" style="float: none;">right</div>
```

[image: Normal flow]

Now, in *scenario 2* you set a `float` property to both `.left` and `.right` elements. As you can see by setting `float: left` to the `.left` element, this element was removed from the *NORMAL FLOW OF THE PAGE*, so `.center` element took his place and shifted upward and if you inspect this `.center` element you will see it has still the same width, it only looks shorter because its left part is hidden behind the `.left` element.

Meanwhile the `.right` element which has `float: right` has also been removed from the *NORMAL FLOW* but it cannot shift upward because there is the `.center` element which has a full-width and doesn't have `float`. For that reason the `.right` element only moved to the right side of the container.

```
<div class="left" style="float: left;">Left</div>
<div class="center">responsive width Main content</div>
<div class="right" style="float: right;">right</div>
```

[image: Scenario 2 with float property]

**SOLUTION**

To fix the problem in *scenario 2* above, you have to make some space for the `.right` element because `.center` element is full-width and is not removed from the *NORMAL FLOW*. To sum up you could make `.center` element shorter and also remove it from the *normal flow* via `float: left`.

```
<div class="left" style="float: left;">Left</div>
<div class="center" style="width: calc(100% - 200px); float: left;">responsive width Main content</div>
<div class="right" style="float: right;">right</div>
```

As you can see now `.left` element goes left, `.center` element goes up and left relatively to the *NORMAL FLOW* from *scenario 1*, and lastly the `.right` element goes up and right relatively to the *NORMAL FLOW* from *scenario 1*.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.center { width: calc(100% - 200px); float: left; }
```

Comment: Thanks! That does solve the issue, do you by any chance understand what causes the issue?

Comment: Sure your center div was trying to span the full width. So I minused the widths of the sidebars from the 100% width.